# Conversion to timestamp and back changes the original time - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I've got dates that I want to change into timestamps, do some process and then change back to the original time.

When I change back, the dates come out not equal to the original dates and times.

I start with this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-02 09:30:00', '2004-01-02 09:31:00',
               '2004-01-02 09:32:00', '2004-01-02 09:33:00',
               '2004-01-02 09:34:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Then I am changing it into timestamps like so:

```
timestamps = [date.timestamp() for date in dates]
```

And back

```
original = [pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp(timestamp) for timestamp in timestamps]
```

And I get:

```
[Timestamp('2004-01-02 11:30:00'),
 Timestamp('2004-01-02 11:31:00'),
 Timestamp('2004-01-02 11:32:00'),
 Timestamp('2004-01-02 11:33:00'),
 Timestamp('2004-01-02 11:34:00')]
```

The time has shifted by 2 hours forward for some reason.

I could've just subtracted 2 hours from every date, but I think that's error-prone because it might have produced more undefined behaviors in an array of a few millions of these that I am not aware of, I prefer to be sure about the method first.

How do I reconstruct the original data?

I am using Python 3.7.6 and pandas 1.0.1

Comment: What problem are your trying to solve with that conversion? Also as a side-note, your Python and pandas version aren't up-to-date.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the note.. I am using a code provided here https://github.com/gmoncarz/renko/blob/master/renko_fast.py which does some logic after calling its new_quotes method, it converts the dates I enter into timestamps to do its logic and I want to get the dates back afterwards in their original human-readable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

> **fromtimestamp(ts)** Transform timestamp[, tz] to tz’s local time from POSIX timestamp.

The point here is *local time*. The difference you observe is your local time's difference to UTC.

`pandas` treats naive datetime (no time zone specified) as UTC. So the correct way to get the original time would be something like

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-02 09:30:00', '2004-01-02 09:31:00',
                          '2004-01-02 09:32:00', '2004-01-02 09:33:00',
                          '2004-01-02 09:34:00'])

timestamps = [date.timestamp() for date in dates] # Unix seconds since epoch (UTC)
# timestamps = dates.values.astype(int)/1e9 # would be more efficient btw.

original = pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s')

# original
# DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-02 09:30:00', '2004-01-02 09:31:00',
#                '2004-01-02 09:32:00', '2004-01-02 09:33:00',
#                '2004-01-02 09:34:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This produces the right result, thank you! as I understand from you, in order to use .fromtimestamp then I would get a result according to my machine's difference to UTC time, in my case I am UTC+2 so 09:30 turns into 11:30, I would need to first convert the times to a different time zone before I can use them

Comment: @orie in general, maybe you can work with aware datetime (time zone set) from the beginning, but it's context-dependent if that works smoothly. The unexpected result you encountered is an example why one has to be careful with the datetime handling ;-)